# Laravel: cache remember forever closure doesn't run

Tags: php

This is an issue for one of my pages, but not for all. For some reason code in the remeberForever() closure doesn't run.

```
        $contentMap = $this->format_content($page);
        sleep(1);
        dd($contentMap);
```

```
    private function format_content(Page $page)
    {
        return cache()->rememberForever('content:'.$page->fixed.':'.app()->getLocale(), function() use ($page) {
            dd("HEY!");
```

Instead of "hey" the contentMap is displayed. The sleep and dd()s are only there for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't see this. Obviously the closure doesn't get called when the cache is already set. After running `php artisan cache:clear` the code runs once, and then skips it. As is intended behaviour.